# Persistent event notifications from Samsung Calendar

Tags: samsung, notifications, calendar

Similar to [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88120/persistent-notification-for-calendar-events), but in my case it's for the *Samsung Calendar* app.

I have *recurring* events that used to generate **persistent** top-of-the-screen notifications.

E.g. 'every Thursday, from 11 to 12 - do X and Y, reminder on time (i.e. at 11)'.
--> every Thursday a notification would appear at 11, *and stay there **permanently**, only disappearing when I manually dismissed it*.

No longer the case: now the notification appears **but then disappears as soon as the event 'end time' is reached** (in this example, at 12).

That means that if I don't look at my phone exactly between 11 and 12, I will miss the notification and probably not do X and Y.
[Not a theory, BTW, e.g. I forgot to put in a tax payment; luckily I was reminded by someone.]

I looked this up on the web, of course, and I found a few similar cases, but no actual solutions, only complicated and cumbersome workarounds (hence my asking here).

To be clear, my goal here is to understand if there are any **settings** I can change to make the notifications behave like they used to.
Stopping using Samsung Calendar would not be an option.

**Any ideas? Suggestions?**

---

PS, for clarity:

- I know I can make events last longer so the notification does not disappear after 1 h, but how long should they be? Days? Weeks? The whole point of having *persistent* notifications is to have them shown to you as reminders of an action that is due; and then you take that action in your own time. Any fixed persistence time can cause you to not take the action and then forget.
- I know I can make *tasks* in Samsung Calendar (which are indeed like reminders of things to do, with no specified duration) instead of *events* (which require a fixed start and end time), but 1) I used events before because they worked, so now I have a long list of them, synced everywhere; 2) Samsung tasks cannot be set as *recurring*, and that's the whole point of most of my reminders (things that I need to do at specific intervals in time).
- I know there are other apps that handle calendars, like Google Calendar, but 1) in my search for solutions I actually found several posts complaining about the exact same issue with that one; 2) as explained, I have a lot of Samsung Calendar events already made, which I wouldn't really fancy rewriting into another app; 3) I have already set up my Samsung account to back up my calendars and other stuff, which I would no longer benefit from if I did that.

Comment: Perhaps you can write to Samsung and ask if they can support the functionality you are looking for in the settings.

Comment: Thanks, good idea! I am used to think that big corporations don't listen to their customers, and here they intentionally changed the behaviour of an app (for the worse IMO). It happened with Google Maps as well. At some point they removed the compass from the navigation view. I and other users wrote about it in a Google forum. There was no response, nothing happened for several months, maybe close to year iirc, and then all of a sudden the compass came back with one update. Maybe one has to hope that the same happens here :/